# Sanity newly added field is not showing on queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'm creating a web application using sanity. I added 'likes' field which is a number, to my post schema. I can see likes on my desk, but when I query `*[_type == 'post']` I don't see likes field. Also, when I try to increment the field 'likes' using patch function, client complaints that the field does not exist. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine these issues are due to **data not yet being in your posts**. Let's break it down:

### Patch error

As you can't increment an undefined/null value, you have to first run `setIfMissing` on your `likes` field to make sure it exists. Here's some pseudo code:

```js
client
  .patch(postId)
  .setIfMissing({ likes: 0 }) // ensure likes exist
  .inc({ likes: 1 }) // And only then increment it
  .commit()
```

### Field not appearing in queries

By default, GROQ won't return empty values. That means that, if your posts don't have `likes` set, you won't even see this property in the data returned from the API.

IF you need likes to show up, you can use GROQ's `coalesce` function to provide a default value to likes. Here's a sample query:

```
*[_type == "post"]{
  ...,
  // Default likes to 0
  "likes": coalesce(likes, 0),
}
```

Hope this helps